# Set specific location of multi JLabel in JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, slideshow

I need to show Background image on full screen that in JFrame, and write on it in two different positions, like this[image]

And this is my code for now and its not work well.

```
JPanel container = new N_BackgroundImage(new ImageIcon(scaledImage), screenIndex);
container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
container.add(sign);
container.add(dateAndName);

// Adding the new Container to the JFrame
getContentPane().add(container);
```

The result is:
[image]

Anyone know how to do what I want to do ?

Comment: Use a `GridBagLayout`?  Use compound layouts (different containers)

Comment: Can you show me an example ?

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct, others are not. Be consistent!!!

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I use different containers the labels will be hidden.

Comment: @noamaghai No they won't - you just need to use the correct layout managers

Comment: So which layout manager I need to use ?

Comment: @noamaghai, `So which layout manager I need to use` - read the tutorial and experiment. For example. Set the layout of your image panel to a BorderLayout. Then you create another panel and add it to the "PAGE_END" of the BorderLayout. I'll let you figure out what the layout manager of the second panel should be. It could be a BorderLayout, or a BoxLayout, or a GridBagLayout. Try it with all 3 and see which you like best. You learn by trying.

Comment: Thank's it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

I split all my JLabels to containers(JPanels) and set them view like I want, after that I added them back into the `imageConainer` like you will see, and add the `imageContainer` into the JFrame.

So my code is like this:

```
JPanel imageContainer;
JPanel dateContainer = new JPanel();
JPanel signContainer = new JPanel();

imageContainer = new N_BackgroundImage(iconToImage(new RotatedIcon(new ImageIcon(scaledImage), RotatedIcon.Rotate.UP)), (int) picWidth, (int) picHeight, screenIndex);

imageContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

dateContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
dateContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 15, 15));
dateContainer.setBackground(new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, .0f)); // Transparent background
dateContainer.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);          
dateContainer.add(dateAndName, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

signContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
signContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 15, 15, 0));
signContainer.setBackground(new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, .0f)); // Transparent background
signContainer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
signContainer.add(sign, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

// Adding the new Layer on too of the image
imageContainer.add(dateContainer, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
imageContainer.add(signContainer, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

// Adding the new Container to the JFrame
getContentPane().add(imageContainer);
```